# Not able to convert dict as pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following dict :

[image]

My goal is to convert it as a dataframe :

|  | Tenor | Type | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EDH3 Comdty | 310 DY | FUTURE_RATE | 3.84000000 |
| EDM3 Comdty | 401 DY | FUTURE_RATE | 3.71999999 |

Doing the following give me a non wanted ouput.

|  | EDH3 Comdty | EDM3 Comdty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | {'Tenor': '310 DY', 'Type': 'FUTURE_RATE', 'Rate': 3.84000000} | {'Tenor': '401 DY', 'Type': 'CASH', 'Rate': 3.71999999} |

Below is what I did try :

```
pd.DataFrame(results.items())
```

The keys should be the index in the wanted output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['Value'].tolist(),index = df['Key'])
```

Comment: The following solve my issue : `pd.DataFrame(DF.values(),index = DF.keys())`